# Failed to download package from Nuget issue in UWP?

Tags: uwp, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I needed to download a package from nuget but had some issue while downloading, some guy suggested to clear the cache of nuget package, after then even when I try to build my project I am getting these errors, I tried multiple networks, different wifi, nothing is working
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's more related with your network quality, you can refer to official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio#nuget-package-manager) and select available package resource. You can ping `api.nuget.org` to check if it could be accessed. If it does not work, you may need network proxy.

Comment: @CoCalceDew i tried different networks nothing worked no matter how good the network is but, using nuget.exe i did `nuget restore project.sln` and it worked

Comment: OK, you could try to repair your VS manually.

Comment: @CoCalceDew i did as i mentioned above

Comment: Can you share your nuget setting screenshot.

Comment: don't have the screenshot thought, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore) is what I did.

Comment: Please open vs tool->options->nuget package manager- > package sources.

Answer (score 0):

update all package that are installed on your solution,
There may be a conflict in the packages.
it's worked for me.